# What's the simple expression to get bigger number from two with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have two number, @n1, @n2, I want to get bigger one in one simple expression like Max(@n1,@n2). How to write the expression for T-SQL?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(n) FROM VALUES(@n1, @n2) t(n)`

Comment: @TI imo this is the best answer, it Works for several values as well. Why don't you post it ?

Comment: @Anon imagine you have 4 variables and need to find the highest. Write the case solution for it. When you are done try the max version and tell me which version you prefer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    @n1 INT = 2,
    @n2 INT = 3

SELECT MAX(n) FROM (VALUES(@n1), (@n2)) t(n)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE WHEN @n1 > @n2 THEN @n1 ELSE @n2 END
```

Comment: @KentZhou there is no IIF in sql server 08 so use case

Comment: @KentZhou I am sure IIF will give you a faster syntax error in sql server 2008

Comment: @KentZhou No IFF. CASE will be the fastest for you [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7866e/2)

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @a int = 45, @b int = 40;
SELECT IIF ( @a > @b, @a, @b ) AS Result;
```

Comment: ahh.. valid in SQL Server 2012 - didn't pay close enough attention to the tags

Comment: IIF is not a built-in function for SQL Server 2008 R2